# Task in gradle to include java class before compile

Tags: java, gradle

I need to create Gradle task which can replace .java files before Gradle build.
Gradle build package app in .war file. And I need to have replaced bytecode there after build.
I tried sourceSets Gradle task but it can only exclude files.

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude 'com/myapp/example/resource/impl/ResourceBundleImpl.java'
            }
        }
    }
```

But I need to also include file in the same place. How I can do it with Gradle?

```
The directory to  file that I need to exclude: com/myapp/example/resource/impl/ResourceBundleImpl.java
The directory to file that I need to include: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/my/ResourceBundleImpl.java
```

To copy file content it is also posible solution.But How can I do it before compile time?

The below task didn't helped, becouse in build file have .java files instead of .classe file.

```
  task prepareSources(type: Copy) {
        from('src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/my')
        into('build/classes/java/main/com/myapp/example/resource/impl')com/myapp/example
    }

// Prepare sources, before compile
    compileJava {
        dependsOn prepareSources
    }
```

The below task throws :
Task :cdx-war:compileJava FAILED
error: package com.myapp.example.util does not exist

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "$projectDir"

            exclude 'com/medtronic/diabetes/carelink/rbps/resource/impl/ResourceBundleImpl.java'

            include 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/my/ResourceBundleImpl.java'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I put classes that I need to replace together and add suffix to one of them and replace this suffix during compile time :

```
   sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs = ["$buildDir\\generated-src"]
            }
        }
    }

    task copySourceSet(type: Copy) {

        println 'Change java class in patient-svc-war'

        from "$rootDir\\patient-svc-war\\src\\main\\java"
        into "$buildDir\\generated-src"

        from file("$rootDir\\patient-svc-war\\**_suffix.java")
        into "$buildDir\\generated-src"
        rename { String fileName ->
            fileName.replace("_suffix", "")
        }

        filter { line -> line.replaceAll('_suffix', '')}
    }

    compileJava.source "$buildDir\\generated-src"

    compileJava {
        dependsOn copySourceSet
    }

    compileJava.doLast {
        delete "$buildDir\\generated-src"
    }
```